# How to plot functions of multiple variables with multiple constraints as a function of just one variable

Tags: plotting, parameters

Essentially I would like to plot the solutions to the following equations in terms of only 2 of the variables included: I have the following simultaneous equations:

```
{f - p == 0,
g - q == 0,
h - r == 0}
```

Where `f`,`g` and `h` refer to complicated expressions in the variables `p`,`q` and `r` as well as a 4th variable `s`. I have been numerically solving the system for various values of `s` between 0 and 1. I would like to plot p against s between 0 and 1, subject to the constraint that all these equations hold. I haven't been able to work out how to do this without parameterizing `q` and `r` in terms of `s` and `p` which I have not been able to do. Is there be any way to directly plot `s` against `p` on this interval (subject to the above equations holding) without paramaterizing?

Comment: It would greatly help if you included the actual definitions of. Your function, or a minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I don't think that f,g or h will fit here but they're as defined in this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215864/having-trouble-solving-a-complicated-system-of-equations/215929?noredirect=1#comment552182_215929